# how to get local image input from user in python?

Tags: python, api, remove.bg

I am building an auto image background remover website using the [remove.bg API](https://www.remove.bg/api#remove-background). I have the following code:

```
# Requires "requests" to be installed (see python-requests.org)
import requests

response = requests.post(
    'https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg',
    files={'image_file': open('/path/to/file.jpg', 'rb')},
    data={'size': 'auto'},
    headers={'X-Api-Key': 'INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'},
)
if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    with open('no-bg.png', 'wb') as out:
        out.write(response.content)
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
```

here on the 5th line, they have added the image path manually so what I should write in this code to get local image input from users just like they access ours??

Comment: What is the 5th line? I can't count that high.

Answer (score 1):

Try an input statement:

```
# Requires "requests" to be installed (see python-requests.org)
import requests

file_path = input("Please insert the path to the image: ")

response = requests.post(
    'https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg',
    files={'image_file': open(f'{file_path}', 'rb')},
    data={'size': 'auto'},
    headers={'X-Api-Key': 'INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'},
)
if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    with open('no-bg.png', 'wb') as out:
        out.write(response.content)
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
```

Comment: Great answer! Note that `f'{file_path}'` can be just `file_path`. There is no need for `f'{}'` when you already have a string.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for pointing that out! I use string formatting so much I'm just in the habit of always using f-strings, but you are correct, it is not necessary in this situation.